# React-native Android error: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCViewPager" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, android-viewpager, react-navigation-top-tabs

I just want to build top tab navigation and I followed the official documentation, I did everything to fix this error, even manually linked but It didn't work (however new versions of react-native have autolinking, I have the latest one ), followed many solutions in the gitHub and other sites, nothing changed, I am working with android device

Even ChatGPT couldn't help me to avoid this error, I installed all of required packages correctly, manually linked after error, cleared cache, restarted project, all of them were useless

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.